# How to give count to a Vim command line command (like :insert, :normal, etc)

Tags: command-line, vim

In Vim as probably all of you know it is possible to give a count to commands in "normal mode" by preceding them with a number.

Like for example `4dd` that will delete 4 lines.

I am wondering if there is a way to pass a count to a vim command line command (a command beginning with colon) to repeat it multiple times.

Something like `2:normal oHi!` to repeat the `normal oHi!` command 2 times.

Is there a way to do something like this within Vim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many :-commands do accept a count as an argument. For example:

```
:delete 4
```

Would delete four lines, starting with the line the cursor is on.

Some :-commands take a count before the command name instead:

```
:2next
```

Would edit the second next file in the argument list.

However, the `:normal` command does not accept a count in either form.  You would have to wrap it in a loop:

```
for i in range(1,2)
    normal oHi!
endfor
```

And of course you could create a user-defined command that did what you wanted:

```
command -count=1 -nargs=+ Normal for i in range(1,<count>) | exe 'normal ' . <q-args> | endfor
```

The `-count=1` sets the default count to 1, and you invoke it the second way:

```
:2Normal oHi!
```